# JSF Trinidad Image tag replace broken images

Tags: html, jsf, trinidad

I'm using JSF with Trinidad tag

I was wondering how can I catch error event like in html img tag

```
<img src="someimage.png" onerror="imgError(this);"/>
```

This is my code:

```
<tr:image source="/../myImage.png">
```

So , I will be able to replace the image with error image.

Thanks,

Jhon.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the best solution is to point the `source` attribute to either a [servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) or a method on a bean, and do some logic there.